# Android LayerDrawable: How to set layer coordinates programmatically?

Tags: java, android

The following XML code of a layer-list ist given:

```
<layer-list>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/my_color_a" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/my_color_b" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

To do some things dynamically I need to rebuild this code programmatically as a LayerDrawable class. This code exists:

```
ShapeDrawable layer0 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
ShapeDrawable layer1 = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {layer0, layer1});
```

How do you translate `android:left="5dp"` to Java code? There is no setter for this property.

Comment: You have the `setLayerInset()` method of the `LayerDrawable` class.

Comment: Yes, but using this function the values apply for all layers, not just a single, specific one.

Comment: try `setLayerInset(layer, leftOffset, topOffset, rightOffset, bottomOffset)`

Comment: Ah, it works! I did not notice that the first parameter selects the layer. Thank you @Luksprog for pointing out the correct function; thank you Saga Pilkhwal for making me facepalm myself!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `setLayerInset(layer, leftOffset, topOffset, rightOffset, bottomOffset)`

Refer to the [LayerDrawable documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) for more help.